# Two way binding variable in Modal - Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a `Bootstrap Modal` that I initialize using `jQuery` as follows:

```
$('#saleModal').modal('show'); // I know I should use the angular way in initializing the modal but...
```

In the `Modal` I have an `input` that I need to bind to a variable as follows:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="toBeBoundVariable">
```

But the binding does not work. How can I tell `Angular` to check for bindings in that `Modal`.

My best guess for the reason why it's not binding is because the `Modal` was initialized using `jQuery`. But, is there a way to tell `Angular`, "Hey, there is a Bootstrap Modal initialized, there are some bindings you need to be aware of".

Here is the code:

```
<!--Modal start-->
 <div class="modal" id="saleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel_4"
 aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel_4">New/Edit Sale</h5>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="ion-ios-close-empty"></i></span>
        </button>
      </div>
  <form>

    <div class="modal-body">

      <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8 mg-t-10 mg-sm-t-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="firstname">
      </div>
      Bound firstname: {{firstname}}
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
      >
        <i></i>Save
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

`.ts` file

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-purchase',
  templateUrl: './purchase.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./purchase.component.css']
})
export class PurchaseComponent implements OnInit {

  firstname: string;

  constructor() {


  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  showModal() {
   $('#saleModal').modal('show');
  }


}
```

Comment: can you share some code you tried, like, the modal component you have created?

Comment: Just don't do it. Either use angular-material/cdk or ng-bootstrap.

Comment: @KomolNathRoy I have updated the question with sample code

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed to add `name` attribute in your input field.

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="firstname" name="firstName">
```

Hope, it solves your problem. Make sure you have imported the FormsModule in your module.

Comment: It worked! I can't believe missing the `name` attribute would cause that issue. Thanks